# Is the depth in CNN network same as chanels for images?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I was studying from a Stanford lecture for CNN and they used W * H * D for images. When using PyTorch, we use channels for images. Is this depth the same as the channels for the initial convolutional layer?

Comment: Yes.‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏ ‏

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the number of channels in a image correspond to the number of (input) layers we need to define for a 2d convolutional layer.
It is also explained in the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) and you will find lots of other tutorials on 2d convolutional layers online (e.g. [here](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/pytorch-conv2d-explained-with-examples/)).

Comment: I have also seen them use Conv2d(1,32,5) when taking the image for the input layer. Why do they use 1 here? Is it because the image is grayscale? Then also the channels should be 2 I guess.

Comment: The first three parameters are given as torch.nn.conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=5). This means you create a convolutional layer that takes in a image with 1 channel (so a grayscale image!), outputs a feature map with 32 channels, while applying a convolutional kernel of size 5x5.
Grayscale images only require 1 channel. So in that example there would be a grayscale image expected as input.